# Does a "static" rendering of a React page always duplicate content in JS objects?

Tags: reactjs

Looking at this isomorphic react page: http://jlongster.com/Presenting-The-Most-Over-Engineered-Blog-Ever

I see that there is a Javascript variable at the bottom of the static content that represents the static content.

So the content is replicated when downloading.

Is this mandatory for the way react works?  Any more efficient methods?

Comment: No you don't have to do it that way. You can pull content using AJAX request, read it from localStorage or any way you prefer. However, I'm not sure to which part of the blog post you are referring. Please update your question with specific code example to get more accurate answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the data included so that you can mount the application on the client.  The initial client side render must produce the same virtual dom as the server gave.

You could fetch it async, and wait until it downloads to mount the app, but there will be a significant delay between when the user reaches the page, and when JavaScript is actually applied.  It'll also double the load on the database for initial requests.

Overall, server rendering will improve the time it takes for the user to see content, improve SEO, enable page caching with a CDN, and other benefits that outweigh the costs by far.

It's less important for sites behind a login, and you can often save significant development time by omitting it.